# C++ function content based on caller

Tags: c++

Is it possible to compile two or more variations of C++ function content with some keyword that directs what gets executed depending on function caller, without need for making multiple copies of full function for each caller?

So far solution has been to use parameters for function and statements to execute depending on caller.

```
V sol::compare(uchar start_lev, V *a , V *b){
solMutex.lock(); // not needed by all callers 
for(auto lev:solVec){ 
switch (lev.group){ 
case a: 
dontRemove=0;
val++; // not used by all callers
return something; 
case b: 
val++; //not used by all callers
return something; 
case c: 
      etc... 
} 
#ifdef QT_DEBUG // not needed by all callers
```

If it possible to code single function and add some keywords, so it compile few variations without overhead of the unused parts of the function depending on different callers.

Comment: That's what parameters are for: for the function to do different things depending on the function call. Otherwise, a function has no means to somehow magically determine who called it.

Comment: Are you looking for templates? Give us a concise sample of the code you want to be able to write.

Comment: It for performance intensive part of program, and would use 4 altered versions of function depending on caller.

Comment: @Flow How much of the code is identical (independent of the caller). Again: Give a concise example code in your question please!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what is the deal with the macro at the end, but you can do what you want like this:

```
template <bool do_lock, bool do_increment>
V sol::compare(uchar start_lev, V *a , V *b){
  if (do_lock) solMutex.lock(); // not needed by all callers 
  for(auto lev:solVec){ 
    switch (lev.group){ 
    case a: 
      dontRemove=0;
      if (do_increment) val++; // not used by all callers
      return something; 
    case b: 
      if (do_increment) val++; //not used by all callers
      return something; 
    case c: 
      etc... 
}
```

To call this, you would then do

```
auto v = sol::compare<false, false>(....);
```

And vary those booleans depending on whether the specific caller needs it. Note that you *have* to  know the booleans you feed in at compile time since the compiler is generating a different function for each combination of booleans. Because the booleans are known at compile time, those branches will (if a bool is false) simply get pruned away as dead code by any compiler.

Comment: Thanks for info , templates appear good way to make easyer to maintain code.

Answer (score 1):

You have subsequently give a sketch of several ideas in a comment.

```
V sol::compare(uchar start_lev, V *a , V *b) {
    solMutex.lock(); // not needed by all callers
    for(auto lev:solVec){
       switch (lev.group){
           case a:
               dontRemove=0;
               val++; // not used by all callers 
               return something;
           case b:
               val++; //not used by all callers
               return something;
           case c: 
               ///etc...
      } 
      #ifdef QT_DEBUG // not needed by all callers
}
```

For the preprocessor there isn't much you can do, codewise.

Aside from that you could use booleans. There are alternatives.

For other patterns, you could separate the commonality and differences. 
For example, if `solMutex` is a member variable of some fictious `sol` calls, we could have a `lockingSol`

```
class sol
{
public:
    V sol::compare(uchar start_lev, V *a , V *b);
        for(auto lev:solVec){
            //etc
        } 
    }
 };


class lockingSol
{
public:
    V compare(uchar start_lev, V *a , V *b)
    {
        solMutex.lock();
        return sol_.compare(start_lev, a, b);
    }

private:
    mutex solMutex;
    sol sol_;
};
```

This allows `nonlockingSol` to call `solMutex.lock();` and then call `sol_`'s method.

The template and stragey desgin patterns give you ways to switch out behaviour.

Alternatively you can send in a functor or lambda to swicth out what happens in the middle of an algorithm. The standard library iteself gives many example of this.

For example consider

```
template< class RandomIt, class Compare >
void sort( RandomIt first, RandomIt last, Compare comp );
```

This iterates over something, and the caller sends in the `Compare` function to vary what happens inside the iteration.